# Simple For loop Issues

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have multiple vectors that I want to compare for overlap. I'm doing this in a for loop but the for loop is not loading the vectors properly. Please find below a reproducable example

```
#creating 4 vectors
TVector1 <- c("test1", "test2")
TVector2 <- c("test1", "test2")


XVector1 <- c("test1", "test2")
XVector2 <- c("test1", "test2")


# creating the list with the for loop
List_intersect <- list()
for (i in (1:2){ # length calculates the length of the vector# iterate from 0 to 19
  identity1 = paste0("TVector", i)
  identity2 = paste0("Xvector",i)
  Intersect <- intersect(identity1, identity2)
  List_intersect[[i]] <- (Intersect)
}
```

It gives a character(0) list

Comment: `(i in (1:2)` here a ")" is missing! 

and with `paste0("text",i)` you will set a string and not refer to the object. To make variable object names you need `eval(parse(text=paste0("text",i)))` or something like this. Happy coding!

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are also better ways to do this, but to make your example work:

```
#creating 4 vectors
TVector1 <- c("test1", "test2")
TVector2 <- c("test1", "test2")


XVector1 <- c("test1", "test2")
XVector2 <- c("test1", "test2")


# creating the list with the for loop
List_intersect <- list()
for (i in 1:2){
  identity1 = eval(parse(text=paste0("TVector", i)))
  identity2 = eval(parse(text=paste0("XVector", i)))
  List_intersect[[i]] <- intersect(identity1, identity2)
}
```